# Book about a planet covered with giant trees and inhabited by angel-like aliens

Tags: story-identification, books

I have very few memories of that book but I do remember:

- One of the two main characters is a woman, foreign to the planet, who happens to be there, I don't remember how or why. She's held captive by one of the planet's natives.
- The alien planet is covered in gigantic trees where the majority of life happens in the heights of the trees.
- The planet is inhabited by an intelligent human-looking species with wide bird wings who live in some sort of nest on top of the trees.
- I guess they were at war or something.
- The book was short and small and the cover was basic, a huge green forest and a couple or maybe just one.
- It wasn't an amazing book; it had an interspecies romance kind of vibe and it wasn't great at it.
  -The story was very short and I read it in French, it was maybe written for youth

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this book?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMOEl.jpg

Comment: Almost fits the Hork Bajir chronicles from the Animorphs series - the planet is covered in giant trees, the native species are an intelligent birdlike people (though they live in the deep valleys), there's a war, one of the two main characters is an alien woman, and she has an interspecies romance with the other main character (a native Hork Bajir).

Comment: Is it possible that you're thinking of Varley's Titan?